# Problems instantiating an extension of a base class

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, collections

I have an empty abstract base class:

```
public abstract class base{ }
```

and two class that extend it:

```
public class a extends base{}
public class b extends base{}
```

and in another class I am referencing it :

```
public class it {

    List<base> list;
    list = new ArrayList<a>; 

    //getting an error above.
    // I thought I could do this?
}
```

What should I try? I was trying to have a list of the base class. Then based upon circumstance, be able to create a list of the two extending classes.

Comment: Please respect Java naming conventions: classes start with an upper-case letter.

Comment: The answer below has it, just an aside point Class names with a Capital letter. public class Base.  public class A extends Base... A tiny point, but it's a big help to stick to the convention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if I wanted to do something like this:

```
List<b> getBList(){

  if (baseList instanceof b ){
      return (List<b>) baseList<base>;
  }
  else return null;

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create the list like this :

```
list = new ArrayList<base>();
```

This list can contain items from types a and b.for example the following is ok

```
A a = new A().
list.add(a);
```

Comment: This answers it well. Worth reading about ArrayList (becoming increasingly useful to me) and generics. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Answer (score 4):

`List<base>` and `List<a>` are not the same type or related in any class hierarchy. Just because the types of the elements in two collections are related does not make the collection instances related.

You can add dervied classes of the `base` to the same `List<base>` instance:

```
List<base> list = new ArrayList<base>();

list.add(new a());
list.add(new b());
```

See [Generics and Subtyping](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/subtype.html) from the Java Tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

`List<Base>` and `List<A>` and different type. They did not have inheritance relationship.

But you can declare like this:

```
List<? extends base> list;

list = new ArrayList<a>
```

See 《Effective Java》 Generics Type.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this code doesn't work is that while all `a` instances are `base` instances, not all `base` instances are `a` instances (such as `b`).

Specifically, `List<base>` means that you can add `a` and `b` instances to the list:

```
List<base> bases = new ArrayList<base>();
bases.add(new a());
bases.add(new b());
```

That will compile correctly, because everything in `bases` is an instance of `base`.

On the other hand, if Java allowed you to use your code:

```
List<base> bases = new ArrayList<a>();
bases.add(new a());
bases.add(new b());
```

Adding the `b` would be adding it to something that should only accept `a` instances. Therefore, Java protects against that by disallowing that statement to compile.